# Flask: Executing multiple queries

Tags: python, flask, mysql-python, flask-mysql

I'm building a webapp, and one of my .py files keep a lot of SQL functions. These functions connect to the database, execute the query, fetch the result and close the connection.

Example:

```
def get_user_data(): 
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host, port, user, passwd, db)   
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "CALL `RANDOM_PROCEDURE`(%s)"
    data = None

    try:
        cursor.execute(query,[random_param])
        data = cursor.fetchone()

    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        return error
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
    return data
```

One of the pages run 3 of those functions before rendering the page:

```
@app.route('/app', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def app_home():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        q1 = get_user_data()
        q2 = get_weather_data()
        q3 = get_product_data()

        return render_template('app/index.html', param1=q1, param2=q2, param3=q3)
```

This page takes too long to load, since the queries are executed one after the other. I have tried to run them at the same time, in separate threads (using Process), but Flask tells me that I'm out of context.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Keep a connection pool of MySQL connections around, don't connect to the database on every function call.

Comment: So I should keep opening/closing cursors under the same conn pool ?